# Nested loop with purrr::walk leaves empty plots

Tags: r, purrr

The following code produces a grid of plots:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)
library(patchwork)


exdata <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  nest %>% 
  crossing(dummy = 1:3) %>% 
  crossing(cohort = LETTERS[1:3]) %>% 
  mutate(plots = map(.x = data, ~ ggplot(.x, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()))


# vars for plot grid
mod <- 'Fair'
colsn <- length(unique(exdata$dummy))
rowsn <- length(exdata$cohort %>% unique)

# create plots
wrap_plots(plotlist = exdata %>% filter(cut == mod) %>% pull(plots), ncol = colsn, nrow = rowsn) + plot_annotation(title = " ")

# add some text across columns
walk2(seq(0.165,0.835, length.out = colsn), unique(exdata$dummy), ~ grid.draw(textGrob(.y, x = .x, y = 0.98, rot = 0)))
```

Looks like this:
[image]

In that code block I have a variable `mod <- 'Fair'`. I would like to make this a vector and produce a grid for each type of cut in diamonds. Tried:

```
mods <- exdata$cut %>% unique %>% as.vector

walk(mods, function(.x) {
  wrap_plots(plotlist = exdata %>% filter(cut == .x) %>% pull(plots), ncol = colsn, nrow = rowsn) + plot_annotation(title = " ")
  walk2(seq(0.165,0.835, length.out = colsn), unique(exdata$dummy), ~ grid.draw(textGrob(.y, x = .x, y = 0.98, rot = 0)))
})
```

This code seems to run without error, but no plots all returned. The grid itself is, just no plots:
[image]

How can I run a nested walk loop to generate a grid of plots for each type of cut?

Comment: try explicitly calling 'print' on the plots inside the expression to be walked?

Comment: Thanks @CaptainHat, nesting wrap_plots inside of print did indeed solve my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrapping your plots in a print statement solves the issue

```
walk(mods, function(.x) {
  print(wrap_plots(plotlist = exdata %>% filter(cut == .x) %>% pull(plots), ncol = colsn, nrow = rowsn) + plot_annotation(title = " "))
  walk2(seq(0.165,0.835, length.out = colsn), unique(exdata$dummy), ~ grid.draw(textGrob(.y, x = .x, y = 0.98, rot = 0)))
})
```

[image]